# How to check if a map address is valid when using addMarker()?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, geocoding

I add a marker to a static map, placed to my google sites as a 'Google apps script'-gadget, via a textbox in the UI. The code I use is:
map.addMarker('isThisAValidAddress');

How can I check in the script that the address the user wrote in the textbox is a valid one?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps doesn't actually validate addresses; that's not what it's made to do. It will point to where the address would be *if it were a real, valid address*, but that's all. Google is an address locator, and it sounds like what you need is a validation tool.

Validating an address ensures that it is a real, deliverable address that you could send mail to -- and that requires having a database (such as from the US Postal Service) of existing addresses to check user input against. You would submit the user input to a verification service (this can be done programmatically), and the service would then tell you whether or not the address is valid.

One such verification tool is [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api), which you can plug into your website really easily with the LiveAddress API [jQuery Plugin](http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/website-forms) (you just copy and paste a few lines of code into your site). Users would type their address into a form or textbox, and LiveAddress would check that data against the list of valid addresses and return a standardized, valid address for the user to approve.

There are other address validation tools available, too. (LiveAddress is just the one I know the most about, since I work for that company.) I'm not a programmer; I just know a lot about addresses. I work at SmartyStreets, and addresses are our specialty.

Updated to add: SmartyStreets now offers [international address validation](https://smartystreets.com/pricing/international) as well as domestic US address validation.